# Repair Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, repair, visual-studio-2010

How can I repair Windows 7?

I want to reinstall Windows without losing my applications. Does such a method exist?

I am having some issues with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (see the image below) - I've repaired it, reinstalled it and applied a new configuration file but the problem still exists. I figure reinstalling Windows might fix the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 is extremely hard to completely uninstall.
You would need the [Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall).

To repair Windows 7 without losing the still-installed applications, see
[How to Perform a Startup Repair in Windows 7](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair.htm).
See also [Startup Repair: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Startup-Repair-frequently-asked-questions).

However, if you still have a system restore point from just before the installation of VS2010, I would restore it rather than reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @haahin: Added some info.

Comment: oh my god. problem is exist yet :( what do i do now?

Comment: I had a feeling this would happen. See for a possible solution: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2005/03/16/5345.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a repair install like you could do with XP, see this article

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

.